# Disable return key in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, keyboard, textfield

Is it possible to disable the return key button of the keyboard if some conditions are not met? I did not find anything like `enablesReturnKeyAutomatically` for SwiftUI. I do not want to change the keyboard type, as I need the presence of the return key, but it has to be enabled only in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible at all in pure SwiftUI. Maybe it can be solved if you create some UIKit Wrapper for UITextField in SwiftUI. Something like this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct CustomTextField: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String
    
    let placeholder: String
    let enablesReturnKeyAutomatically: Bool
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(text: $text)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
        @Binding var text: String
        
        init(text: Binding<String>) {
            _text = text
        }
        
        func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
            text = textField.text ?? ""
        }
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {
        let textField = UITextField(frame: .zero)
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        textField.placeholder = placeholder
        textField.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = enablesReturnKeyAutomatically
        
        return textField
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiTextField: UITextField, context: Context) {
        uiTextField.text = text
        
        if uiTextField.text?.isEmpty ?? false {
            uiTextField.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = true
        } else {
            uiTextField.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = false
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text: String = ""
    @State private var isFirstResponder: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            CustomTextField(text: $text, placeholder: "Enter text", enablesReturnKeyAutomatically: true)
        }
        .padding(.all)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

The above solution does not work at 100%. It's just an example.